# Setting android permissions in Icenium

Tags: android, icenium

I've developed an android app using Icenium Graphite.  When I install my app onto my phone, it always displays a long list of permissions that my app supposedly needs approval for prior to installation.  The only thing my app needs are the camera and sound recorder.  When I add these permissions in via the Properties page in Graphite and remove all other permissions, my app still keeps asking for permission for everything in creation (location, contacts, etc.)  upon installation to a device.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Cordova 3.0.0 framework that comes with a set of core plugins. The core plugins let you access native system functionality such as the accelerometer, camera, compass etc. By default Icenium includes all of those core plugins. They require some additional Android permissions so when you build your project, the build process adds these permissions by default.

The next Icenium version would let you disable the core plugins that are not required by your application and this would eliminate the need of the additional Android permissions.

Comment: Any idea when this next version will be released?

Comment: The next version would be released in the following few days, so stay tuned !